# WordPress payment hooks not working for WP Crowdfunding products

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Let me put the code that I have tried so far.

Basically, I am trying to capture payments when they are successful by creating a function in the function.php file, the code is provided below.

```
    add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'capture_donation_for_custom_donation_view', 10, 1);
    function capture_donation_for_custom_donation_view($order_id){
        if ( ! $order_id ) {
            return;
        }

        global $product;
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
```

This function captures the data from the order object and works fine for normal orders. But I am using a plugin WP Crowdfunding to create some crowdfunding projects and data is not being captured through payment hooks.

Comment: Why not checking order status ? and check if order item is crowdfuncting product ? 
From the plugin i found those hooks - crowdfunding_order_type and crowdfunding_new_order_item. So on order status changed to completed (payment is successful ) you can check the order and look for this item and go from there.